Looking for record of a deceased Italian worker on the Panama Canal between 1882 and 1891
Carlo Nigro (c 1855 - c 1890) was living in Calvello, Potentenza, Basilicata, Italy, when he and his younger brother Michele went to Panama, sometime between 1882-1891, to work on the Canal for the French. Carlo died there, and Michele disappeared, and presumably died there as well. Unfortunately I have no information on their exact date of arrival or dates of death. They do not seem to have headstones in any Panamanian worker cemetery.
Are there any record repositories for Italian workers that might have this information?

Here is a useful website that might help you to find the answers you are looking for.
https://www.italianside.com/basilicata/potenza/calvello/genealogy/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I found a bunch of Carlo Nigro relatives on www.myheritage.com
https://www.myheritage.com/research?action=query&formid=master&formMode=1&qname=Name+fn.Carlo+fnmo.1+ln.Nigro+lnmo.3&qevents-event0=Event+et.any+epmo.similar&qevents=List&useTranslation=1&tr_funnel=supersearch
